# Why is `$(this).children` not working in the following code?

Tags: jquery

Why is `$(this).children` not working in the following code?

```
$('.home-box').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('home-box-caption a').animate({
    bottom: -12,
  }, 200);
}, function(){
  $(this).children('home-box-caption a').animate({
    bottom: -24,
  }, 200);
});
```

[image]

```
.home-box {
background: url(images/home_box_bg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
margin: 25px 13px 25px 0;
position: relative;
width: 230px;
height: 160px;
}
```

When I hover `.home.box` nothing happens.

Comment: just add dot to the selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the selector you use for the `children()` function, you forgot to add the dot character (`.`) to indicate a class name for `home-box-caption`.

The selector should be

```
$(this).children('.home-box-caption a').animate(...);
//----------------^
```

Comment: Are there no other errors in your console? Also, you're manipulating the `bottom` property in the animation, are you sure this actually has an effect on the CSS? Perhaps the element doesn't have the correct `position` value...

Comment: It used to work when I had `$('.home-box-caption a').hover` and using only `$(this)` strange.

Comment: No errors, and an alert works. It just the animation I think.

Comment: Yep... sounds to me like it's just an issue of manipulating the CSS...

Comment: But nothing appears in element style of my chrome inspector. Strange.

Comment: I figured out. I had to use `find` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the dots in the JQuery selectors...

Should be `$(this).children('.home-box-caption a')`

instead of `$(this).children('home-box-caption a')`

Answer (score 4):

You forgot it's a class. so put `'.'`

```
.home-box-caption a
```

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a `.` class notation in the `.children()` selector:

```
$(this).children('.home-box-caption a')
//----------------^-----------------------try adding this.
```